# AzureDevOps Build Pipeline task 50 minutes to publish artifact

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have created a build definition that builds my mobile application. The final step is to publish the .apk artifact. This file sits at 100mb as it is a debug build. but the agent is taking +50 minutes to publish it. Surely this is not right.

We are using a self hosted agent sitting on a VM.

**Console Logs**

```
##[section]Starting: Publish Artifact: STARS.Mobile.Android.$(BuildConfiguration)
==============================================================================
Task         : Publish build artifacts
Description  : Publish build artifacts to Azure Pipelines or a Windows file share
Version      : 1.151.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts
==============================================================================
##[section]Async Command Start: Upload Artifact
Uploading 1 files
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Uploading 'STARS.Mobile.Android.Debug/com.app.apk' (7%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
...
```

How do I increase the speed of this.

Comment: maybe you could find out more if you set the `system.debug` variable to `true`?

Comment: Does this case occur all the time, or just occasionally?If it is the former, you can check if the vm you are using is the same as your region. If not, you can modify the region of vm to your location, which will increase the speed.If this happens occasionally, this may be the reason for the server.

Comment: This doesn't help with your specific problem but just as a reference.  I have an artifact that is ~100MB on a hosted agent and it runs the publish step in 11 seconds.

Comment: It look more like slow network.